# How to configure my ESP8266 such unique that Android App can scan and connect only with it by smartConfig

Tags: android, arduino, udp, iot, esp8266

I am working on such IoT project in which I have to connect my ESP8266NodeMCU-Amica to Android App by `smartConfig`. Now the problem is that, for better security and privacy, Android App should detect only my ESP8266 for `smartConfig`. Means, Android App should not detect and transmit any data packages(should not give SSID and Password) to any other esp8266 which is not mine. Which protocol or method should I follow? I am coding in ArduinoIDE.

I have already used most popular `smartConfig` Android App[[1]](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cmmakerclub.iot.esptouch&hl=en_IN) for trial and got succeed[[2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAxsi.jpg). But still can't decide how to detect only my own ESP8266 (no any other esp8266) via Android app for the same smartConfig method.

I have also seen so many links and chats for UDP broadcast packets and successfully tried it for ESP8266 and UDP sender/receiver AndroidApp[[3]](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jca.udpsendreceive&hl=en_IN). But it can be helpful only when ESP and Android will be in the same LOCAL network. And for my case, ESP8266 will not have SSID and Password before smartConfig.

I am expecting this matter is limited to the UDP packets[broadcast] only. If not then, how other professional smart devices are configured to be scanned and connect with their own mobile App..? I mean, some professional App can only scan and connect with their own specific devices, not with any other devices for `smartConfig`.

Comment: So, you want to change ssid and password without uploading code again and again, right?

Comment: No, I can successfully change ssid&pw without uploading code again and again. But for security purpose, I want such method through which Android App can scan and detect only my ESP8266 for smartConfig, not any other's esp8266.

Comment: I have noticed that ESP8266 is not directly taking data packets from Android App. Router is giving data packets to softAP running on ESP8266's server at port 80. prefer this link,  https://tttapa.github.io/ESP8266/Chap05%20-%20Network%20Protocols.html